# How to persist messages in Actor and reply after failure(JVM crash)?

Tags: jvm, akka, actor, akka-stream, akka-persistence

I'm going to use actors for more than 5000 clients to deliver messages to them when they arrive.
If a client disconnects the clients messages stored in respective Actor's mailbox.But if jvm crashes all the messages in the actor mailbox will flushed.
If i use persistence actor i will store each messages of an actor in disk?? then reply to actor like mailbox on disk?

Answer (score 1):

The broad approach would be to use Akka Persistence (this sounds like a reasonable fit for event sourcing) so that the state of the actor can be recovered.  You would choose and set-up a persistence backend (e.g. the local leveldb one or a DB at network distance like MySQL/Postgres or Cassandra) for the events to be stored.

Note that messages in the mailbox are not persisted; only those messages which get processed by the actor can persist state changes.